# Is there any way to loop 2 foreach and one for loop together?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-collection

I am working on Laravel 8 project where i shall create Human Resources Management System, so i struggle now with reporting of employees attendance.
I have 2 model
`User.php` and `Attendance.php` also 2 controllers and relation between the models.

```php
public function attendances()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attendance::class, 'user_id');
}
```

This is coming from my `AttendanceController.php`

```php
public function index()
{
    return view('frontend.attendances.index', [
        'employees' => $this->userRepository->getAllUsers()
            ->with(['attendances' => function($query) {
                $query->where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id);
            }])
            ->get()
    ]);
}
```

So now i have to display table with all dates in current month and to show does each user were present on work or not.
I have this is my `summary.blade.php`

```xml
@foreach($employees as $employee)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle mr-2" width="30" height="30" src="{{ $employee->image ? $employee->image : asset('assets/images/user.jpg') }}" alt="{{ $employee->firstname }}" data-original-title="{{ $employee->firstname }}">
            {{ $employee->name() }}
        </td>
        @php($count=0)
        @for($i=1; Carbon\Carbon::now()->daysInMonth >= $i; $i++)
            @foreach($employee->attendances as $attendance)
                @if($i == Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s', $attendance->check_in)->isoFormat('D'))
                    <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-check text-success"></i></td>
                    @php($count++)
                @else
                    <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i></td>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endfor
        <td class="text-success text-center">{{ $count }} / {{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->daysInMonth }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This is not the way how it should work, but i have tried it in many ways and still cannot find some proper way.
Here is picture what i am trying to achieve, and what i have with my code
[image: Picture of the final result]

[image: My result]

Comment: What is the problem? What should it show?

Comment: It should show the data as it is on the image.
With the current loops it continues the `<td>` for each attendance... Basically the loop goes from 1 to 31 January and display only one attendance, after that it continue again and shows the second attendance etc... so my January doesn't end at day 31... it will have as much as attendances i have (31 x attendances)
I have updated the question with picture what i wanna achieve and what i have

Comment: I think it's a combination of 2 problems: 1) You might not have an `Attendance` for each day of the month in question and 2) You're loading every attendance in the `$employee->attendances` relationship (even the ones that are not relevant to the current month). To know for sure, more details on the `Attendance` model is needed (migration, casts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this: loop through the dates and filter attendance for the employee based on the date.

```
//First, create a date period. 

//use Carbon\Carbon; use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
$daysOfThisMonth = CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(),  Carbon::now()->endOfMonth());
 
//Loop through the days 
foreach($daysOfThisMonth as $day){
 //firstWhere will return one row if day exists in check_in field (equivalent to true), otherwise will return nothing, which will be equivalent to a false.
 if( $employee->attendance->firstWhere('check_in', $day ) ) //formatthe dates according to your preference
   echo "attended - print tick";
 else
   echo "not attended - print x";
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted!